Нужна ли запятая перед "ещё"?
Работать на возвышенности ещё и в стесненных условиях – работа трудная.


Допускаются  два варианта, причем выбор по произношению:

(1) Работать на возвышенности (ещё и) в стеснЕнных условиях – работа трудная. Неоднородные отношения
(2) Работать на возвЫшенности, (ещё и) в стесненных услОвиях – работа трудная. Однородные отношения.
Такая вариативность будет считаться стилистическим недостатком, также нежелателен повтор однокоренных слов (работать, работа).

Редактирование:

Работать на возвЫшенности, да ещё (и)  в стесненных услОвиях – труд тяжелый.
Пояснение: Использован присоединительный союз ДА ЕЩЕ, также возможен ДА ЕЩЕ И.
